# Rasterized EPSG 4326

Tags: coordinate-system, data, epsg, rasterization

I'm looking for a rasterized world map using the EPSG4326 projection, but haven't been able to find any ones online (or at least decent quality ones that appear that the top left does correspond to -180, 90). Perhaps I don't know what to search for.

Can anyone point me to a resource with such a pre-rasterized image?

If not, how would I go about producing such an image?

Comment: You should know that EPSG:4326 is not projected. it has coordinates in Lat-long in WGS84 Datum & Elliposid. It's up to the Software on how to render the data.  Most GIS Software just use plate carrée to show the data. With this information, what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: Also, have you looked at: http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Sorry if I was unclear. I'm interested for ESPG:4326 for that reason (sorry for the incorrect terminology)! I want a rasterized world map that I can easily calculate the x, y of a lat/long pair. Namely given `lat` and `lon` in degrees and `img_width`/`img_height` in pixels, `x = (lat + 180) / 360 * img_width` and `y = (lon + 90) / 180 * img_height`. It looks like what you linked may be exactly that. I'm downloading it now. Thanks for the suggestion! If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: What kind of data are you looking for? Land areas? Political boundaries? Climatic data? Night lights? Elevation? Other?

Comment: Ah, sorry for still not being specific. Optimally, I'd like a map of political boundaries at the country level.

Comment: It's not so common to find rasters of country boundaries. But I've added a simple work around answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this data from Natural Earth should help you out: http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/

Answer (score 1):

@Devdatta Tengshe's answer will get you to some good data, but the available rasters don't include political boundaries that you're looking for (it's more common for country boundaries to be in vector formats). But you can still use the natural earth data by converting the Admin 0 vector data (http://www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/) to a raster. Just choose a cell size that suits you.